# Passing values from PythonTeX to LaTeX

Tags: tex-core, python, datenumber

I have read in the PythonTeX manual about how to pass LaTeX values to PythonTeX, but I cannot find any documentation (or a way) to do the reverse. For example, in the LaTeX package datenumber, one passes `<year>`, `<month>`, and `<day>` to `\setdatenumber{<year>}{<month>}{<day>}` in order to set `\thedatenumber`, a counter defined by the package. I want to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{datenumber}

\begin{document}

\pyc{year = 2015}
\pyc{day = 2}
\pyc{month = 3}

\setdatenumber{\py{year}}{\py{month}}{\py{day}}

\end{document}
```

But, datenumber gets frustrated and tells me its missing number. Is the problem the way I'm using PythonTeX or just the way datenumber works?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datenumber` probably expects numbers, or at least fully expandable macros. PythonTeX macros are not fully expandable.

Getting this to work is similar to [using PythonTeX with `siunitx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122004/10742).  You could create a command that wraps the `datenumber` command. The wrapper command takes the arguments, performs any processing, and then sends back a `datenumber` command using the processed results. You probably want something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{datenumber}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pysetdatenumber}[3]{%
  %Store variables on Python side
  \pyc{year = #1; day = #2; month = #3}%
  %Send back datenumber command to use variables on TeX side
  %Could also use \pyc with print()
  \py{r'\setdatenumber{{{0}}}{{{1}}}{{{2}}}'.format(year, day, month)}}

\pysetdatenumber{2015}{3}{2}

\datedate

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your solution works perfectly. But, I'm not understanding why you have to put two sets of delimiters, e.g., `{{0}}`. Why does one set cause an error?

Comment: @fiziks In [Python's `format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting), replacement fields are delimited by braces, and braces are doubled to be literal. So `{0}` is field zero, and `{{` is a literal left brace. `{{{0}}}` is field zero, surrounded by a literal brace on each side.